# Most pythonic way to add object to string?

Tags: string, python-3.x, standards

I have a Java background and I'm trying to learn Python. Let's say I have an array and I want to print out its length along with a string. In Java, I would do this:

`System.out.println("The length of the list is " + myList.length);`

However, I don't know what the accepted way to do this is in Python. Would I do this:

`print("The length of the list is " + str(len(my_list)))`

Or this?:

`print("The length of the list is {x}".format(x=len(my_list)))`

What is the most accepted, pythonic way to do this sort of thing? If so, why?

Comment: I feel this is more of a stylistic thing.  Which one do you like better?  Personally, I like the first one better.

Comment: Or maybe `print("The length of the list is %d" % len(my_list))`?

Comment: @StephenRauch I read that using `.format()` is preferred in Python 3.x onwards.

Comment: These days I generally use `format`, but for a simple conversion the `%` also works great and is clear and concise.  If you insist on format, you do not need the `x` in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python ≥ 3.6, you can also do:

```
print(f'The length of the list is {len(my_list)}')
```

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals

If you want to interpolate an instance of a custom class into your string, just make sure it has a `__str__` method.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 ways to put a string representation of an object into a string, but I would recommend none of them for this case:

- Concatenation: `print("The length of the list is " + str(len(my_list)))`
- Old-style formatting: `print("The length of the list is %d" % len(my_list))`
- New-style formatting: `print("The length of the list is {}".format(len(my_list)))`
- f-strings: `print(f"The length of the list is {len(my_list)}")`

Instead, just utilize the fact that `print` can do this for you!

```
print("The length of the list is", len(my_list))
```

Note how you don't need to cast it to a string, and that I removed the trailing space from the string literal: `print` automatically puts a space between its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the best way is up to you, but Python recommends to use `.format()`

And like `System.out.printf` in Java, you can also write

```
print('The length of the list is %d' % len(my_list))
```